# Unable to compile code when using OrderClose class

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm

I'm trying to build a plugin that does some operations on a salesorder. I also have to set a order as fulfilled. I found on the SDK documentation an extract that must be used to fulfill the order in the right way

```
var request = new FulfillSalesOrderRequest
        {
            OrderClose = new OrderClose
            {
                SalesOrderId = new EntityReference 
                    { LogicalName = orderEntityName, Id = orderId }

            },
            Status = new OptionSetValue(newStatus)
        };
```

The problem is that the code cannot be compiled because MVS says "The type or namespace name 'OrderClose' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)". RightClicking on "new OrderClose" (OrderClose is underlined in red) I cannot see the Resolve section in the menu. 
I have also tried this way:

```
        var request = new FulfillSalesOrderRequest();

        request.OrderClose = new OrderClose();

        request.OrderClose.LogicalName = orderEntityName;
        request.OrderClose.Id = orderId;
        request.Status = new OptionSetValue(newStatus);
```

How can I make the code compiling (and hopefully working)?

Comment: Sounds like you are missing an assembly reference. You need to include any assemblies that the SDK requires in order to reference the SDK objects.

Comment: Yeah but FulfillSalesOrderRequest is under  Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages  namespace and I have already include it.

Comment: That doesn't necessarily mean that `OrderClose` is in the same assembly.  Have you confirmed that it is?

Comment: Looking at FulfillSalesOrderRequest in the documentation it seems that OrderClose is a property of FulfillSalesOrderRequest class of type Entity (that is a standard CRM type)

Comment: Again, just because `FulfillSalesOrderRequest` may make use of `OrderClose`, such as exposing an instance of it through a property, that doesn't mean that it's in the same assembly.  You need to confirm exactly what assembly `OrderClose` is actually defined in.  Take a look at @pittofdirk's answer; he's on the right track.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Which "CRM" are you using? Dynamics?

Comment: @Nathan A the OrderClose property of FulfillSalesOrderRequest is of type Entity

Comment: ...Ok, then why are you trying to create a `OrderClose` instance?  Instead, you should be doing `request.OrderClose = new Entity();`

Comment: I tryed also this way (and it compiles) but when I execute the request to fulfill the order I receive an Exception saying "An unexpected error occurred.".

Comment: That's another question all together.  If `OrderClose` isn't a class/struct, you cannot create it with `new`.

Comment: Of course. I initially thought it was part of the SDK. Anyway now I don't understand why I receive that error :)

Comment: I'd suggest you post a new question with your source code and error details, so you can get the answer you are looking for.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Since `OrderClose` is not a class, but the name of a Property, you cannot create it using `new`.

As the property is of type `Entity`, you need to create an instance of `Entity` like this:

```
request.OrderClose = new Entity();
```

Answer (score 1):

That is an early bound request, that's why you can't compile, if you aren't using the CrmScvUtil.

This is an example of a late bound request:

This namespace is needed.

```
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Messages;
```

And this is the code.

```
var request = new FulfillSalesOrderRequest();
request.OrderClose = new Entity("orderclose");
request.OrderClose["salesorderid"] = new EntityReference("salesorder", new Guid("YOURGUID"));
request.Status = new OptionSetValue(100001);
service.Execute(request);
```

`100001` is the status code for Complete.

If you want to handle the response, use a variable to receive the answer.

Answer (score 0):

OrderClose is in the Assembly "Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Proxy" (in Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Proxy.dll)

Have you added Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Proxy.dll as a reference? Not just

```
using Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages;
```

but actually going over to the solution explorer pane and right clicking References > Add Reference and choosing Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Proxy.dll.

Edit: Right clicking on something red-squigglied and picking "Resolve" won't work unless the correct assembly is referenced.

Comment: I have already added Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Proxy to the project and used Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages in the code

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the sample code assumes you have generated the early-bound code for your organization. If you included the early-bound code in your project, this reference would resolve. See this link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327844.aspx

The CrmSvcUtil.exe is part of the CRM SDK. Here is a template of how to use it:

```
CrmSvcUtil.exe /url:http://<serverName>/<organizationName>/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc    /out:<outputFilename>.cs /username:<username> /password:<password> /domain:<domainName>    /namespace:<outputNamespace> /serviceContextName:<serviceContextName>
```