# Cannot set salesorder to fulfilled

Tags: c#, plugins, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm trying to set a certain sales order to Fulfilled state. The plugin executes on the update of a salesorderdetail.

```
        var request = new FulfillSalesOrderRequest();

        request.OrderClose = new Entity();

        request.OrderClose.LogicalName = ordineEntityName;
        request.OrderClose.Id = orderId;
        request.Status = new OptionSetValue(newStatus);

        service.Execute(request);
```

But when I execute the code I receive an Exception with "An unexpected error occured" message.

Any suggestion?

Comment: How is this not a duplicate of your earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28730095/unable-to-compile-code-when-using-orderclose-class?

Comment: It's a different problem. I thought it was better to create a new question.

Comment: Also, whenever you have a question about an exception, you need to post the complete exception. The best way to do this is `try {/* code */} catch (Exception ex){MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); /* or whatever */ throw;}`. Then post the result of `ex.ToString()`.

Comment: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault]: An unexpected error occurred. (Fault Detail is equal to Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault).

Comment: Please post that in the body of your question. Also, is that the _full_ exception? Post the results of `ex.ToString()`, please.