# CancelSalesOrderRequest OrderClose not found when initializing OrderClose = new OrderClose()

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

```cs
CancelSalesOrderRequest cancelRequest = new CancelSalesOrderRequest()
{
    OrderClose = new OrderClose
    {
        SalesOrderId = new EntityReference(salesOrder.LogicalName, salesOrder.Id),
        Subject = "Close Sales Order " + DateTime.Now
    },
    Status = new OptionSetValue(-1)
};

service.Execute(cancelRequest);
```

The type or namespace OrderClose could not be found! Any solution for this ? I have added assemblies and references which are required.
[image: The type or namespace OrderClose could not be found]

Answer (score 1):

**[Solved]** Below is working code, I referred another question which was about fullfillorder and close sales order and made some changes in my code which resolved my issue.

Here is the link for fullfillorder and close order : [Unable to compile code when using OrderClose class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28730095/unable-to-compile-code-when-using-orderclose-class/46820278#46820278)

```
var request = new CancelSalesOrderRequest();
request.OrderClose = new Entity("orderclose");
request.OrderClose["salesorderid"] = new EntityReference("salesorder", new Guid("your order's guid here"));
request.OrderClose["subject"] = "Close Sales Order" + DateTime.Now;
request.Status = new OptionSetValue(-1);
service.Execute(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is just a simple compile error due to not either having Earlybound Entities generated, or referenced.  You can either use the CrmSvcUtil from the SDK, or if you prefer having a UI, the EarlyBound Generator in the [XrmToolBox](https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/).  Once your entities are build and referenced, you'll have full compile time type safety.  Your answer is just using the late bound approach, which doesn't require generating any classes, but doesn't have any compile time type checking.